# What is the full list of log entries in Analogue: A Hate Story?

Tags: analogue-a-hate-story

Inside the game you can type in a document ID to bring up any log entry regardless of whether or not the AI has granted you access to them. This can be used to "cheat" your way to 100% completion without going through the game multiple times.

What's the list of such IDs? I don't feel like playing through the whole game again for just one entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go, you filthy cheater. You are probably looking for either entry 6-1 (that's 6-22A) or entry 7-7 (that's 7-EUX25). You're welcome.

> The way to obtain 6-1 "legitimately" is to *not* show it to *Hyun-Ae at all. That's really annoying, since showing *all* the things to *all* the AIs *is* the way to progress in the game.
>
> You can obtain 7-7 legitimately from *Hyun-Ae but then it is very hard to also show it to *Mute in order to get the best ending. The document code is the easiest way to achieve that.

Remember: unlocking the documents with the code is *not* enough to have them count towards your completion percentage: the entries that count for completion are the ones you *win* with. The Tab or Ctrl key is your friend: hit it to automatically skip through all the dialogue you've already enjoyed.

Oh, and in case you are wondering: with the exception of 6-5 and 7-7, AIs have nothing to say about messages that would otherwise remain locked. *Hyun-Ae, for example, has nothing to say about block 8. I checked so you don't have to.

---

Here goes:

1. Block 1

   1. 1-X01
   2. 1-B01
   3. 1-B09
   4. 1-X08
   5. 1-X14
   6. 1-B13
   7. 1-X15
   8. 1-XB16
   9. 1-B15
2. Block 2

   1. 2-XA02
   2. 2-Q3
   3. 2-1288
   4. 2-XA79
   5. 2-Q19
   6. 2-1309
   7. 2-XB26
   8. 2-Q43
   9. 2-XC10
3. Block 3

   1. 3-DE08
   2. 3-EX94
   3. 3-AA01
   4. 3-DY78
   5. 3-11X
   6. 3-123
   7. 3-EZ33
   8. 3-8192815
   9. 3-EX99
4. Block 4

   1. 4-SM921
   2. 4-EZ14
   3. 4-SZ035
   4. 4-GA788
   5. 4-192A
   6. 4-142
   7. 4-2030
   8. 4-14A
   9. 4-ZA830
5. Block 5

   1. 5-IR1
   2. 5-EU22
   3. 5-TT8
   4. 5-EU54
   5. 5-EU9A
   6. 5-EU8A
   7. 5-EUA2
   8. 5-EUX12
   9. 5-IO3
6. Block 6

   1. **6-22A**
   2. 6-EUX27
   3. 6-EUX71
   4. 6-SA589
   5. *6-EUX85*
   6. 6-SA611
   7. 6-EUX98
   8. 6-EUY03
   9. 6-EUY22
7. Block 7

   1. 7-HH78A
   2. 7-EUX20
   3. 7-HH92X
   4. 7-TG0
   5. 7-EUX24
   6. 7-HJ02F
   7. **7-EUX25**
   8. 7-HZ11B
   9. 7-TI5
8. Block 8

   1. 8-J9I8XVMA
   2. 8-J9I8XVMB
   3. 8-J9I8XVMC
9. Block 9

   1. 9-AREW
   2. 9-ASBA
   3. 9-IX3
   4. 9-TA6
   5. 9-TB2
   6. 9-ATAQ
   7. 9-TK1
   8. 9-ATZS
   9. 9-TR8
10. Block 10

    1. 10-QF392
    2. 10-RZ001
    3. 10-RZ011
    4. 10-RZ021
    5. 10-RZ031
    6. 10-RZ041
    7. 10-RZ051
    8. 10-RZ061
    9. 10-SA500
11. Helpful notes

    1. 11-AA01
    2. 11-AA02
    3. 11-AA03
    4. 11-AB04 or 11-BB01 (see comment)
12. *Mute's questions

    1. 12-AA01
    2. 12-AA02
    3. 12-AA03
    4. 12-AA04
    5. 12-AA05
    6. 12-AA06
    7. 12-AA07
    8. 12-AA08
    9. 12-AA09

Comment: You're missing one code: 11-AB04 is Hyun-ae's version of 11-BB01 ("Smith family tree"). Funnily enough, it uses the exact same image for the family tree in both cases (smithfamily.png), despite Mute's assertion that Hyun-ae made a "cluttered mess" out of it in her version.