# How can I get to the Harem ending in Analogue: A Hate story without cheating?

Tags: analogue-a-hate-story

Although it is possible to get to the Harem ending [via](http://blog.room208.org/post/20396672085) [cheating](http://www.player1diary.net/achievement-guides/analogue-a-hate-story/), I would like to know if it is possible without manually entering the relevant [document codes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/82019/8557) (using knowledge from a previous play through).

I have tried following the advice of [Zachary Paul Clement](http://jayisgames.com/archives/2012/02/analogue_a_hate_story.php) who suggests that it is possible to unlock those entries in time, but every time I try I can't complete the relevant interactions before

> the reactor meltdown occurs.

So, are there any reliable steps I can take to get to the Harem ending by legitimately unlocking the required entries, or is it really *impossible*, as the "2 Girls, 1 Core" Steam achievement descriptions suggests?

<sup>If it makes any difference, I am playing the Steam version of A:AHS. It would be good to say if any solution requires a specific version of the game.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below we have someone who is personal friends with the developer, explicitly stating that you have to use information from a previous playthrough.

> In Analogue: A Hate Story, there's no way to romance both of the available characters at once...**unless you play through the game multiple times and use information you learn on earlier runs to break the fourth wall in a new run**. Doing so nets you the 2 Girls, 1 Core achievement, which about 24% of all players have attained.

Quote from http://kotaku.com/the-steam-achievement-that-nobody-unlocked-1610073943

Comment: But it still doesn't explain *how* to do so.

Comment: @Frank To be fair the answer negates the need of a how because he is basically saying that the only way to do it is the way the op has outlined in the question.

Comment: @Colin For the purposes of the answer, that is irrelevant.  The point of an answer is to *answer* the question.  Not kinda sorta tell you how to go about maybe figuring it out.

Comment: @Frank I don't agree, the question is two parts, 1) is X possible? 2) if X is possible how do I do X? The answer says X is not possible. You are asking him to explain how to do something that, in his opinion backed by a reasonable source, is not possible.

Comment: @Colin Which is being said in an incredibly roundabout way.  Because that's nowhere near how I interpreted this attempt at an answer, at all.  This is not an answer, because it doesn't *answer* the question.  It hems and haws around it, without actually providing one.

Comment: @Frank I agree that the answer could have been more concise but I think it does answer the question. Maybe you can review my edit since you have a wealth of rep. ;-)

Comment: @Frank and even pre-edit it is still a better answer than the one provided by LoLeRJi that basically says, "I tried Y and failed let me know if you find an answer"

Answer (score 0):

I actually found something that might be of use to you; while in the meltdown process, just do what you should to switch to pss and make the reactor ready for shut down, but down shut it down yet, instead return to the AI interface. Mute will tell you a few things then ask you if you have something to show her or something like that (I don't remember what exactly the options were but you'll undertand what I mean when you get there) just pick the options that would make her copy Hyun-ae to her own core, yes, you can make *Mute copy Hyun-ae to her own core while you are facaing the meltdown danger. I tried to make her somehow show me all of Pale Bride's diaries but couldn't manage to do that.

Hope you can find a way to do what I couldn't because I really want to finish the game with ending 5 WITHOUT cheating and I think there is actually a hidden trigger that would let you get it without cheating, since I played VNs with hidden routes which are supposed to be found by extreme VN players, but I am not one so I couldn't find those, not this time either.

(And I am playing steam version too)

Comment: Thanks LoLeRji, and welcome to Arqade, I didn't realise that, it may not be a full answer, but it may help get us part of the way there.

Comment: I am glad if I was able to help. Besides, I do want to get this ending without having to rely on the knowledge you can only get from having finished the game for at least once. So yeah, please inform us if you can manage to get this ending without "cheating", that would be awesome.